# C++: parsing JSON string, having keys not enclosed into double quotes

Tags: c++, json, casablanca

I've been using Casablanca Json C++ library (cpprest) successfully for some time. Its parser (`web::json::value::parse(<json_string>)`) works perfectly on *valid* JSON strings. Say this will be parsed correctly:

```
{
  "key1": [["1", 0.4], ["0", 0.6]],
  "key2": true,
  "key3": 1,
  "key4": [{"key41": 1}, {"key42": [1,2,3]}]
}
```

Now, I faced the necessity of parsing JSON objects, the keys of which are not enclosed into double quotes:

```
{
  key1: [[1, 0.4], [0, 0.6]],
  key2: true,
  key3: 1,
  key4: [{key41: 1}, {key42: [1,2,3]}]
}
```

Is there a nice way to correctly parse this and then serialize into a valid JSON, so that Casablanca can parse the resultant valid JSON correctly?

[Hjson](https://hjson.org/download.html) seems to work for this purpose, but it doesn't provide the required library for C++. They mention `jzon` library for C - I tried it: it has only one-way parsing (no serialization), and even parsing doesn't work correctly (can't even parse valid JSONs)

Comment: So you're asking for a 3rd party resource being capable of that, knowingly that kind of questions is _off-topic_ here?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Is he asking on converting the "" to none? Thats what i am understanding . Ok im gonna start anwsering

Comment: Do you, by any chance, have control over whatever generates this? So that you could make it generate valid JSON?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ nope, i haven't said this.. any nice c++ preprocessing parsing solution would work just fine too. but if someone knows a 3rd party library, why not?

Comment: @littlepootis nope, if I would - I wouldn't have this problem at the first place

Answer (score 1):

This probably won't be the fastest way to do this, but if niceness is measured in least lines of code, it'll come up pretty high.

What you have is a javascript-like object. Let's plug it into a javascript engine and use it to spit out proper JSON. I'll use Qt's `QJSEngine` since I'm passably familiar with it:

```
constexpr char const* str = R"({
    key1: [[1, 0.4], [0, 0.6]],
    key2: true,
    key3: 1,
    key4: [{key41: 1}, {key42: [1,2,3]}]
})";

QJSEngine e;

QString script = QString("JSON.stringify(%0)").arg(str);
```

then you can just evaluate it:

```
e.evaluate(script).toString().toStdString()
```

yields

```
{"key1":[[1,0.4],[0,0.6]],"key2":true,"key3":1,"key4":[{"key41":1},{"key42":[1,2,3]}]}
```

Comment: thanks! hm, this is interesting approach. I'll give it a shot soon

Answer (score 0):

This crude method will work.

(Untested code )

We've got three states, NEUTRAL, ONSTRING, and ONALNUM.

We start in NEUTRAL. If we hit '"' we go into ONSTRING. If we hit alpha we go into ONALNUM. If we go into or out of alnum, we emit a quote. We also emit the character read.
If we are in ONALNUM, we get out of it when we hit non-alnum, amd go into NEUTRAL, unless we hit quote, when it's a parse error. If we are in ONSTRING we apply JSON string escape rules, which I don't know offhand.

```
 #define NEUTRAL 0
 #define ONSTRING 1
 #define ONALNUM 2

 int state = NEUTRAL;
 char *inptr = str;
 char ch;

 while( (ch = *inptr++))
 {
    if(state == NEUTRAL)
    {
       if( isalpha(ch) )
       {
           emit('\"');
           state = ONALNUM;
       }
       else if(ch = '\"')
          state = ONSTRING;
       emit(ch);
    }
    else if(state == ONSTRING)
    {
        /* JSON string escape rules here */
        if(ch == '\"')
          state = NEUTRAL;
        emit(ch);
    }
    else if(state == ONALNUM)
    {
       emit(ch);
       if(!isalnum(ch))
       {
          state = NEUTRAL;
          emit('\"');
       }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

### Problem

It seems by the context of your question that you want the "" removed so you can have a proper JSON format.

For the JSON parsing part, you should use a library. I'm going to post an example of it here, soon.

### Solution

In order to do that, we are going to use the `std::replace` function from the `<algorithm>` library; although we can implement this on our own, it is better to use standard libraries since the creators of them worked hard on optimizing those function to the fullest capabilities. So let's take your code you gave us from the question and make it JSON-appropriate.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

void convert_char(string &s,char from_conv, char to_conv) {
  std::replace( s.begin(), s.end(), from_conv, to_conv); // replace all 'x' to 'y'
}

int main()
{
    string str =  "{ \n \
    \"key1\": [[\"1\", 0.4], [\"0\", 0.6]], \n \
    \"key2\": true, \n \
    \"key3\": 1,  \n \
    \"key4\": [{\"key41\": 1}, {\"key42\": [1,2,3]}] \n }";;
    convert_char(str,'\"',(char)0);
    cout << str << endl;
}
```

You can see here we have a function called `convert_char` which converts a certain character to another. So basically as your question asked we removed the double quotation, and tada, it is formatted like JSON! Take a look [**here**](http://cpp.sh/3n2l) for the demo.

### Solution to JSON Parser

Obviously, here you will use a library to do this for you. I'm going to introduce `sciter` to you! Basically, with `sciter` all you got to do is:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sciter>

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    string str =  "{ \n \
    \"key1\": [[\"1\", 0.4], [\"0\", 0.6]], \n \
    \"key2\": true, \n \
    \"key3\": 1,  \n \
    \"key4\": [{\"key41\": 1}, {\"key42\": [1,2,3]}] \n }";;
    sciter::value str_conv = sciter::value::from_string( str, CVT_JSON_LITERAL );
    cout << str_conv << endl;
}
```

Now according to this code, the JSON Formatted code is in `str_conv`! References to guide you through this are below in the References section.

### References:

[sciter](https://sciter.com/forums/topic/how-to-loop-through-json-string-create-json-object/)

[cpprefrence `std::replace`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/replace/)

[`string::replace`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/)

[cpprefrence `std::refrence_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace)

### Glossary

**`std::replace`** :

Prototype:

```
template <class ForwardIterator, class T>
  void replace (ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last,
                const T& old_value, const T& new_value); //source cpprefrence
```

references: [cpprefrence](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/replace/)

**`<algorithm>`**:

Many topics are inside the algorithm library. It's a library for, you guessed it, algorithms.

The header `<algorithm>` defines a collection of functions especially designed to be used on ranges of elements.

> A range is any sequence of objects that can be accessed through iterators or pointers, such as an array or an instance of some of the STL containers. Notice though, that `algorithms` operate through `iterators` directly on the values, **not affecting** in any way the structure of any possible container (it never affects the size or storage allocation of the container).
>
> The algorithms library defines functions for a variety of purposes (e.g. searching, sorting, counting, manipulating) that operate on ranges of elements.

References:

[cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/)

[cpprefrence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm)

Comment: Other way round. JSON insists on quotes round identifiers and strings.

Comment: Even if this was what the OP wanted, the correct way would be to use the erase-remove idiom, not leave the string full of `'\0'` characters.

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean This has been fixed. Look at new answer ;)

Comment: thanks, but I don't think that this helps. For the second part (parsing) - I don't have any problems - I mentioned that I extensively use Casablanca library for JSON - with no issues. The first part (replacing "") wouldn't work either - because there're still double quotes surrounding the VALUES inside JSON pairs, not the keys only

Comment: @amanuel2 `replace` does exactly that - replaces elements. You're putting a `(char)0` - C null terminator in every place a `"` used to be. Try to passing `str_conv.c_str()` to `cout` and see what's happening.

Comment: @krzaq ahh!!!! Thanks so much! Thats why i had so many null terminators in my other C++ Codes! Ok i should do ' '... again my bad sorry :-(